# Static Home Page *WITHOUT* /blog Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog that is almost two decades old with thousands of posts. I do not want to change my permalink / directory structure.

I'm currently using the permalink setting **Day and Name** so permalinks look like this:

domain.com/2017/01/17/sample-post/

I'm working on a custom theme, which I would like to have use a static home page which displays the seven most recent posts: one as a splash and the next six displayed below, with a link to the rest of the blog.

I do *not* want the rest of my blog posts to appear in a domain.com/blog subdirectory.

I've found dozens of explanations online of how to move my posts *into* a domain.com/blog subdirectory, but not the reverse.

I *think* my question is basically, "If I use front-page.php as a template for my home page, how can I get domain.com/page/2 to use index.php?"

Comment: @Johannes Well, no. I appreciate the thought, but that won't help. I can't be constantly remembering to update the categories of posts. I want the seven most recent posts to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm open to any solutions someone else might offer, but I don't think there's any simple way to do this.
My solution was to:

1. name my home page front-page.php
2. use code to check if the $paged variable is < 2 and display custom home page content
3. display the Loop if $paged is >= 2

I don't think it's very elegant, but it allows me to do what I wanted.